# transmitter for raspberry pi

Tags: hardware, wireless

I want a transmitter that can be interfaced with the Raspberry Pi for sending live video to a receiver which is connected to a laptop and located at a distance of approximately 1 km. 
I was thinking of using xbee transmitter and receiver for this purpose, but its data rate is 256 kbps which is quite low and I need a transmitter which can transmit at a faster rate.

Can anyone provide me with the options that i can use?

Comment: 3G internet dongle might do the trick. still offtopic here.

Comment: If you have 1km line of sight, then there are 1km range bluetooth dongles like this one: http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/communication/bluetooth-2-stick. You need to have it on both sides.

Answer (score 4):

That kind of range needs directional antennas, which send a concentrated beam of data that does not interfere with other radio signals.

Problem is the source and target should not be moving. Directional antennas at this range are more "legal" (mostly because nobody will complain from interference and because it is extremely difficult to lock into the beam) than using omni directional like traditional devices.

It so happens a company called Mikrotik have these awesome directional antennas (Certified in most of EU and Americas) with built in "Routerware OS" with some devices that can do 10mbs up to 20km, or 200mbs within up to kilometre!

[SXT lite5 For $59](http://routerboard.com/RBSXT5nDr2) which is a 5Ghz, 54mbs 25milliWatt (unlicensed legal), full duplex, directional transceiver!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*If* it's legal where you are (you may need an amateur radio licence), [high-speed multimedia radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_multimedia_radio) can do 1 km line-of-sight with the right antennae. It's a complex system to set up, though. There is a project deploying it on the Raspberry Pi: [HSMM-Pi](http://hsmmpi.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a 3G dongle if you have a seperate IP address. Most Internet providers give NAT IP addresses and this doesnt work in your case. I contacted my Internet provider and got 2 SIMs which are on a VPN(they can talk with each other using the IP address.)

In this method here are the steps you follow.

1. Install Netcat on Pi and Laptop
2. Get the 3G dongles configured on Pi and Laptop so they can ping each other
3. In laptop set netcat to listen on a specific port.(and transfer the received stream to mplayer)
4. In Pi use netcat to forward the video stream to laptop's IP and port

You can also use VLC in which case you don't have to use netcat. The laptop's VLC player just access the VLC server installed on Pi.

If you can't get an IP address you can still use ffmpeg/motion to stream from Raspberry to some streaming service such as Justin.tv

When choosing a 3G dongle please find one with a good uplink speed. Most 3G dongles such as e220 have limited uplink speed.(around 300 kbps). New 4G dongles have better uplink speed.

When using dongles you might need to provide separate power.

Comment: Thanx for rplying but this is not feasible for me beacause i need it at a place where there will be no internet connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Just use normal Wifi Components where you can plug in a custom directional Antenna, then you are fully legal! We have a whole mesh routing network in our city, using just commodity hardware, and never had a problem. Data Rates are like in a 10 Mbit LAN! That should be enough for streaming video, if it is encoded wisely.

Here is a Map of the Network:

https://map.funkfeuer.at/wien/

Comment: That is impressive - how long did it take to get to this stage?

Comment: Some years. I think they started around 2000.