# Raspberry pi with drone for live streaming

Tags: wifi, streaming-video, streaming

I just got a drone, although it doesn't have live video streaming, so I got an idea.

I'll attach my pi to the drone, put a $7 webcam on the drone, and stream the webcam to my laptop.

But, that requires an internet connection. So my question is, is it possible I can attach a mini wifi router to the drone? Also to and connect the pi & the laptop to the router? Basically stream to drone with LAN.

Where can I get a wifi router to do this? A mini one. (The drone can hold all of this, it is powerful)

Comment: I don't think wifi is viable for drones except within a very limited volume, which might be expandable via repeaters -- but there is no such thing as a super powerful wifi router by way of which you will be able to stream things whilst flying hundreds of feet around.

Comment: Related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13315/transmitter-for-raspberry-pi Please have a look if the solutions discussed there apply to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [wifibroadcast](https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/) which uses off-the-shelf WiFi hardware :

> **Why normal wifi is a bad choice for FPV applications**
>
> - Association: Video transmitter and receiver need to be associated. If one device looses association (for example due to too weak signal strength) the video transmission stops instantly.
> - Error-free transmission: Wifi transmits either data that is correct or no data.
> - Two-way communication: Even if you are sending data only from source to sink a bi-directional data flow is required using wifi. The reason for this is that a wifi receiver needs to acknowledge the received packets.
> - One to one transfers: Unless you use broadcast frames or similar techniques a normal wifi data flow is a one to one connection.
>
> **What wifibroadcast makes different**
>
> Wifibroadcast puts the wifi cards into monitor mode. This mode allows to send and receive arbitrary packets without association.
>
> Additionally, it is also possible to receive erroneous frames (where the checksum does not match). This way a true unidirectional connection is established **which mimics the advantageous properties of an analog link**.
>
> Wifibroadcast uses Forward Error Correction to archive a high reliability at low bandwidth requirements. It is able to repair lost or corrupted packets at the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do that with your pi already!

Adafruit has a nice guide here: https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point?view=all

As far as signal strength goes, the 802.11b/g/n USB dongles sold at Adafruit are quite good. I was able to get a signal strength of -74dBm through 14 feet of dirt (both dongles were buried in the ground as an experiment): https://www.adafruit.com/product/814

I imagine that through the air they would perform admirably.